# Dynamically writing subject in send mail task in ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Sorry if the question is already asked.

I have created a ssis package which loads the data from excel file to sql server database.
I logged this information in sql server 'SYSSSISLOG' table using the logging feature in ssis.
Here i need to send the information that was captured in SYSSSISLOG table using send mail task. 
How can i achieve this without using script task,because i am not good in writing c# code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Put the information into a variable and use the variable in the send mail task.
If you don't already have this information in a variable, and can't get it in your current dataflow depending on what type of logging you're using. you could select the data from your log table with a sql task and return the result as a variable.